# Github Copilot not generating code - output gives proxy error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, github, proxy, github-copilot

I've downloaded and installed Github Copilot for my vscode coder workspace twice but when I write comments to enable copilot to generate code, nothing happens.

In VScode when I go to View-> Output it says:

[ERROR] [promptlib proxy] [2024-01-12T14:34:12.595Z] {}

[ERROR] [promptlib proxy] [2024-01-12T14:34:12.596Z] {}

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest official version of Copilot extension works for me.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot&ssr=false#overview

I manually download the .vsix file, and then import it to extension, following:
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72rEW.png).

(The image is borrowed from [here](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_44201981/article/details/128821088))